# Define elements that bust cache on save

Tags: plugin-development, cache, elementcriteriamodel

I wrote a little plugin that reads some entries (Events) from my events section, orders them in a calendar-like structure and returns them to be displayed in a template. (I couldn't do this twig-only)

Now, I would like to use `{% cache %}` on the calendar. I know that Craft normally busts the template cache when updating/adding an element if it detects, that those elements were used in a cached template.

Now as I am fetching the elements in my custom plugin with

`$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);`

I assume, that Craft can't know when to bust the cached output of the plugin.

Is there a way (with the TemplateCacheService for example) to make sure that this cache also gets busted when saving/updating one of my events?

I wonder if I can do this just in twig or if I would have to put a hook before the element gets saved? How does it relate to the cache key?

Any hints, which direction to take?

Thank you,

Robert

---

## Update:

Okay, I'll provide some more details:

My Plugin looks (simplified) like this:

```
// MyPluginVariable.php: 
public function getMonthWithEvents($month, $year)
{
    ...
    $criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
    $criteria->section = 'events';
    $criteria->date = ['and', '>='.$monthStart, '<='.$monthEnd];
    $eventsInMonth = $criteria->find();

    $month = [];

    // Put events in month array with dates etc....

    return $month;
}
```

In the twig template, I do this:

```
// agenda.twig
...

{% cache %}

    {% set month = craft.migrosAgenda.getMonthWithEvents(10, 2016) %}

    {% for day in month %}
        ...
        <div class="day">
            {{ day.date|date('d.M.Y') }}
            {{ day.event.title }}
            {{ day.event.date }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to know for sure without seeing some plugin code, but my guess is you'll want to use the [TemplateCacheService's](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplateCacheService) [includeElementInTemplateCaches](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplateCacheService#includeElementInTemplateCaches-detail) similar to how [BaseTemplate's](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php) [_includeElementInTemplateCaches](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/etc/templating/BaseTemplate.php#L77) does.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my question with some more details and plugin code. I don't understand yet how I would relate the event elements to that certain cached template part. Do I need to use a special key `{% cache key = "xy %}` and refer to that in the plugin? Would it also be a easier solution to maybe read the event elements in twig normally with `craft.entries()` and then pass it to the plugin?

Comment: Update: I used the `includeElementInTemplateCaches` in my plugin as you proposed and it works perfectly. I had to understand the idea, that it is doing this while being "inside" a cache tag and therefor I don't have to relate it to a certain templatecache :) Thank you!